# Json dependsOn ignored

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-rm-template

Hi I have this code which deploys some vm's and a vpn solution, however it deploys the `"vmRdsDeployment"` before the vnet is deployed. I've tried several different variations of dependsOn but nothing seems to work

The error is:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 18:38:57 - Resource Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers 'ilb-m21-m21-m21-vpn-rds' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidResourceReference",
    "message": "Resource /subscriptions/0309443f-e9d3-4974-9a9a-08a476b6ae2e/resourceGroups/RG-VPN-TEST/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET-M21-M21-M21-VPN 
referenced by resource /subscriptions/0309443f-e9d3-4974-9a9a-08a476b6ae2e/resourceGroups/rg-vpn-test/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ilb-m21-m21-m21-vpn-rds 
was not found. Please make sure that the referenced resource exists, and that both resources are in the same region.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "Resource 
/subscriptions/0309443f-e9d3-4974-9a9a-08a476b6ae2e/resourceGroups/RG-VPN-TEST/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET-M21-M21-M21-VPN not found."
      }
    ]
```

Template: https://pastebin.com/rKRP5htc

Comment: hey, in general this means what it says. your loadbalancer called `ilb-m21-m21-m21-vpn-rds` is trying to use virtual network called `VNET-M21-M21-M21-VPN` but its not in the same resource group, or not in the same region. again, hard to be more specific, as all the resources are hidden in nested templates

Comment: @4c74356b41 Hi, thanks, the issue is that the ilb-.. shouldn't be created yet as that should depend on the vnet being created first. There's a section called "vmRdsDeployment" that creates the ilb, which is supposed to be dependant on the vnet, so the vnet gets created and then the ilb gets created, but the deployment seems to start for some reason, when the vnet deployment hasn't finished

Comment: hey, which deployment creates the vnet? if what you say is true, after first failure your template should work on the second run (or at least fail with a different error, because the vnet will be there from the first deployment)

Comment: @4c74356b41 yep, agree totally, however it looks like the vnet doesn't get created. It's a nested template (in variables section), also the vnet is deployed using "vnetTemplate" name.. if that makes sense

Comment: ok, if the vnet doesnt get created you should definitely look as to why it doesnt get created? probably gets created (else you would get an error) just with a different name?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Actually that's a very good point.. I'm using a test subscription which is empty so can see if anything gets created .. doesn't :(  But you must be right, it thinks the vnet has been created, as it seems to continue, but the vnet is a nested template.  No error until it starts to deploy the rds section

Comment: check if you are deploying to the right subscription?

Comment: @4c74356b41 I've checked the subscription, def right one. But have taken out everything from the resources except Vnet deployment and it doesn't deploy it, so I've changed "condition" from false to True and its got a bit further, what does that "condition" true\false do?

Comment: condition can be used to block resource from deploying. true means deploy, false means skip

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks, looks like the switch was set to false, which meant the vnet was being skipped.. but set to true and its all working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the error seems to be due to vnet being conditioned to not deploy with `"condition": false`, after changing to `true` everything worked as expected.